# How to sum up numbers without the sum function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to know how to sum up 3 numbers (A1, A2, A3, A4) in Excel just by using the "=" function and to pull the cell down.

It is an excercise for our class.

The sum should be placed in cell A6.

```
  A   B   C
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
5
6 (formula): "= A$6 + A1"
```

Formula: I go to cell A6 and write there the formula.

Now I place the cursor into A1 and drag the cursor downwards until I reach A4 (in order to tell excell that it should always increment the y part of"A1").
But this does not work.

How it is done properly.
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I could tell you, but then you would be cheating. No, actually, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can write in A6:
`=A1+A2+A3+A4`
You can write it the same and press `Enter`
Or with selecting do the following
Write = in A6
place the mouse in A1
write +
place the mouse in A2
write +
place the mouse in A3
you can continue the same to add more
press `Enter` when finish
don't use the same cell as the formula (+A6 in A6) it will give error (circular reference)